# Phase of Fourier Transform in Python

Tags: python, fft

I have the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftshift

def FourierTrans(S, t):
    fs = 1 / (t[5] - t[4])
    y = fft(S, len(S)*10)
    n = len(y)
    fshift = np.arange(-n/2,n/2)*(fs/n)
    yshift = fftshift(y)
    return fshift, yshift


def InvFourierTrans(Amp, freq):
    fs = 1/(freq[6]-freq[5])
    signal = ifft(Amp, len(Amp)*10)
    n = len(signal)
    time = np.arange(-n/2, n/2)*(fs/n)
    signal = fftshift(signal)
    return time, signal

plt.figure()
t = np.arange(-2.5, 2.5, 0.001)
sigma=np.diff(t)[0]*10
theta = 10000*t**2
y = np.exp(1j*theta) * np.exp(-t**2 / (2*sigma**2))
xnot, Snot= FourierTrans(y, t)
xinv, Sinv= InvFourierTrans(Snot, xnot)
plt.plot(xinv,np.angle(Sinv),linewidth=1,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(xinv, abs(Sinv)/max(abs(Sinv)),linewidth=1,linestyle='-')

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I expected np.angle(Sinv) to be the same as np.angle(y), but it is not. How could I retrieve theta from Sinv? (knowing that abs(y) and abs(Sinv) agree perfectly regardless some shift in the x-axis).

Comment: Using `np.angle` on your FFT output is the correct usage. However, the angle output only goes from -pi to pi or -180 to 180 if `deg = True`. There is no way differentiate between phases with 2pi difference, so it can't possibly match your `theta`.

Comment: sorry, what I meant that the np.angle(Snot) I am getting has nothing to do with np.angle(theta)

Comment: Your theta is a pure real value, `np.angle` gets the angle from a complex number, so it will always return 0. I'm not sure why those two values should be equal.

Comment: sorry again, what I meant is that the np.angle(Snot) I am getting has nothing to do with np.angle(y)

Comment: The gaussian part of your `y` is rounding down to 0 due to precision limits so your phase information is getting lost. That might be why.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `InvFourierTrans` into:

```
def InvFourierTrans(Amp, freq):
    fs = 1/(freq[6]-freq[5])
    Amp = fftshift(Amp)
    signal = ifft(Amp, len(Amp)*1)
    n = len(signal)
    time = np.arange(-n/2, n/2)*(fs/n)
    signal = fftshift(signal)
    return time, signal
```

this solved my problem